# Android エミュレータでGoogleマップが表示されません。

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, flutter

現在、Macbook proを使ってGoogle Mapと連携した避難所アプリを作成中です。
エミュレーターの位置情報がデフォルトだと米国に設定されていましたので
当然、周辺の避難所は表示されません。
エミュレーターの位置情報を東京周辺に変更しようと、Androidエミュレーターの
「Extend Controlls」からLocationの設定に移動したのですが
Google Map自体が一切表示されません。
GoogleMap APIキーの再発行やAndroid studioの最新アップデート
Google Playstore対応のエミュレーターに切り替えるなど試行錯誤を繰り返しましたが
Google Mapは全く表示されないのでご指導の程いただけると幸いです。
回答お待ちしております。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: まず、エミュレータに純正のGoogleMapをインストールして正常に動作することを確認してはどうでしょう。エミュレータも実機と同じくGoogleにログインする必要があります。そのためのアカウントも必要になります。これらが正常に動作している場合で、自アプリだけが不良の場合にはパーミッション周りを確認する必要があるかと考えます。

Comment: Androidエミュレーターのアップデートを実施して、こちらの設定画面には反映されました。ただし、自作アプリには一切反映されていない現状です。